# Github Desktop doesn't recognise my copied folder from external source which contain .git files

Tags: git, github, clone

So I tried to work on a project in two laptops. I've committed this project folder into Git via Github. Then I move this project folder into local Google Drive folder, and let the Google Drive sync it into the new laptop. On the new laptop, I have downloaded Github Desktop and have signed in to my account. Now, the folder is already synced from Google Drive, but I don't see any repo on the Github Desktop. When I click on the + button on Github Desktop, I see "Add", "Create", or "Clone" only. How can I have the same Github repo entries like on the previous laptop without cloning (as the files to be cloned is already here via Google Drive) ? If there's no way to do that, I know that I can just always clone from the repo, and then overwrite the local repo with the files from the Google Drive so that the most recent changes (which I still haven't ready to commit yet) is there. But I'm just curious if it's possible. Thanks.

PS: I've already open terminal on the folder, run `ls -aef`, and see the `.git` hidden folder is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a **bad idea to use the Google Drive** synchronisation with a Git folder. Git's purpose is to sync your projects already, you should not let another program do that before git !

You have to clone your project and then do **commit - push - pull** between your PCs.

*Why do you want to use Google Drive if you commit your code on GitHub ?*

---

Anyway, you just have to **click on "Add"** and **locate your local git repository**. Then it should take a minute to display your branch commit and all the files.

Let me know if it helped :)

Comment: Yeah, ultimately I clone the project and then replace the files with the most recent uncommitted files. I know it's not ideal, but let me see if I can make this works. Thanks!